# How to add a favicon to a nextjs app structure? - possible hydration issue

Tags: next.js, favicon

I'm trying to figure out how to add a favicon file to a next.js app (with react 18).

I have made a _document page that has a head tag as follows:

```js
    import * as React from "react"
    // import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client'
    import { ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react"
    import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"
    import Favicon from "../components/Favicon"
    
    export default class AppDocument extends Document {
      static getInitialProps(ctx: any) {
        return Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <Html lang="en">
            <Head>
              <meta name="theme-color" key="theme-color" content="#000000" />
              <meta name="description" content="name" key="description" />
              <meta property="og:title" content="title goes here" key="title" />
              <meta property="og:description" content="description goes here" key="og:description" />
              <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
              <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"  />
             
              <Favicon />
            </Head>
            <body>
             <Main />
              <NextScript />
            </body>
          </Html>
        )
      }
    }
```

I then made a component called Favicon with:

```js
    import React from "react";

    const Favicon = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
    
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
                <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
                <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
                <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" />
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" />
    
            </React.Fragment>
            )
    }
    
    export default Favicon;
```

I then made a root/packages/src/public folder (this folder is at the same level and place as the pages folder that has the _document.tsx file) and saved each of the assets to it.

I don't get an error, but the favicon does not populate in the browser tab.

How can I add a favicon in nextjs?

I also tried removing the Favicon component and moving the meta tags directly to app.tsx. It still doesnt render the favicon.

I can see from the console errors that the files are not found. They are all saved in the project at public/[file name]. Public is a folder at the same level as the pages directory.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem might have something to do with this post - but i can't make sense of what it says: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem. You need to add the image to the public directory. Next engine will detect this `favicon` automatically.

[image]

but if you need to add special image or etc, you must add image file into `public/static` folder. and your url should be start with `static/*`. like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <link rel="icon" sizes="76x76" href="static/apple-touch-icon.png" />
</React.Fragment>
```

And finally, to display the icon in the browser tab, you must perform a hard refresh `Ctrl+F5`;

Answer (score 1):

I have working a working favicon in a Next.js 12 + React 18 app by adding the icon link directly to the `<Head>` and the images in public/[file name].

```
render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

I assume that your React component is not working because the browser is trying to load the favicon before the page has been hydrated with any Javascript that can generate your React component favicon.

Comment: how could I check the hydration point?

Answer (score 1):

So this applies only if you are using NextJS 13.2 or later. There was a head.js solution, but that was deprecated for what seems to be the final solution. A [metadata object](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head#supported-head-tags) that will live in the `layout.js` and `page.js` files. They will are supposed to override each other as needed based on hierarchy. This link has all of the available properties of the metadata object https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should just add/replace the icon file with the name favicon.ico in the root of the public folder with your icon. If you want to do SEO consider using ["next-seo"](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo) package

What I do, I create a component say Meta.tsx and use it inside my Pages

```js
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo"
import type { OpenGraph } from "next-seo/lib/types"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

import type { MetaProps } from "../../types/content"

export const Meta = ({
  type = "website",
  siteName = "My-site-name",
  data,
}: MetaProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const router = useRouter()

  // TODO Make generator based on different data
  const seoData = data
  const locale = "en_EN"
  const baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL || window.location.origin
  const currentURL = baseURL + router.asPath

  const seo = {
    title: seoData.title,
    titleTemplate: `%s - ${siteName}`,
    defaultTitle: siteName,
    canonical: currentURL,
  }

  const openGraph: OpenGraph = {
    title: seoData.title,
    type,
    locale,
    url: currentURL,
    site_name: siteName,
    images: seoData.images,
  }

  const metaLinks = [
    {
      rel: "icon",
      type: "image/svg+xml",
      href: "/favicon.svg",
    },
    {
      rel: "apple-touch-icon",
      href: "/touch-icon-ipad.jpg",
      sizes: "180x180",
    },
    {
      rel: "mask-icon",
      type: "image/svg+xml",
      color: "#0d2e41",
      href: "/favicon.svg",
    },
    {
      rel: "icon",
      href: "/favicon.ico",
    },
  ]

  return (
    <NextSeo
      {...seo}
      openGraph={openGraph}
      additionalLinkTags={metaLinks}
      noindex={data.requireAuth || data.noIndex}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: And then how would I render it? I have made a public folder at the same level as the pages folder. There is a file in it which is saved as favicon.ico - I cant figure out how to use it in next js _document.tsx

Comment: I usually don't use it in the _document.tsx. What I do is that I create a component say Meta.tsx the inside I use "next-seo" and use the component inside my pages. For meta. If I would want it to be globally used I include it inside my Rootlayout.tsx. I am updating  my answer in a minute

Comment: I don't want to us e the seo package. there must be a way to use a favicon with next js. do you know how to do that?

Comment: I haven't figured that out, I will come up with the answer once I have figured out that

Comment: thank you very much for your help. i don't know why this isn't covered in the docs -surely it's supported by next js

Comment: Absolutely It had to be in the docs, I will be watching for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the correct rel attribute. This works in my project:

```
import {Html, Head, Main, NextScript} from 'next/document';

export default function Document() {

    return (
        <Html lang="en">
            <Head>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/site/images/favicon.ico" />
...
```

where `/site` from `/site/images/favicon.ico` is in the public folder.

Comment: I have tried adding the favicon links including favicon.ico to both the app.tsx and document.tsx files, and tried adding them as an import statement that includes /public (being the name of the folder in which they are saved) to the link address. I cant find a way to get next to recognise either the favicon or the title in the browser tab

Comment: The icon doesn't always show up right away but the above does work. When you inspect the site and and do a shift refresh do you see the query on the network tab?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to update the browser tab with either the title or the favicon - where I use a similar filing convention for the favicon.

Comment: I have made it a favicon

Comment: Several of the tutorials exclude the type tag on favicon.ico (they include it on the other formats generated by favicon generator)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Head from "next/head";

<Head>
    // If favicon path is public/images/
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />

</Head>
```

Then you can render this inside Header component or Lay out component. this
`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />` should work also in `_document` page if you pass correct `href

Comment: I tried this in _document.tsx - but cannot get it to display in the browser tab I'm confident that the file path from src/public is correctly set out in the link tags

Comment: try using in Head component

Comment: do you mean a head tag?

Comment: @Mel yes. The way How I showed on answer is the way how I use for my website

Comment: @Mel did you set correct  type `type="image/x-icon" ` in _document page

Comment: I have tried it with and without an type attribute. When I try with that attribute, i have tried with both x-icon and png. None of these appraoches work

Comment: your file  name should be favicon.ico

Comment: you can convert png to .ico here https://favicon.io/

Comment: I used favicon generator to make all the files. I have a favicon.ico file in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just put the <Head> in your layout component.

```
import Head from "next/head"
const Layout = ({ children, home }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/svg" href="/icons/YOURICON.svg" />
          ....rest of your <meta> tags for SEO ....
        </Head>
        ....rest of your html/jsx like page header/main-stage/footer/etc..
)}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add it via either app.tsx or document.tsx - so that I can use the same favicon on all pages?

Comment: yes, if you `import Head from "next/head"

Comment: In document.tsx, I import head from 'next/document' - is that the issue? It seems odd that I can't find a way to make this work, from document.tsx

Comment: I tried replacing import head from next/document with next/ head in _document.tsx and get an error rendering the page. I think that is not the correct solution.

Comment: actually, it depends which version of NextJS you are using. you should mention which version because things change fast. I am still using 12.3.1 because I started learning when 12.3.1 was out. But if you are using NextJS v.13 then see this document https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

you can run `npx next --version` in project dir to find which version you are using

Comment: I am on version 12

Comment: I am on version 12.3.1 and I have been using _app.tsx, layout.tsx component. I put Head from next/head in my layout. Then all my pages are wrapped in that Layout component so my icon and title etc are visible across all pages

Check this github repo for code sample: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that let's me do this from document.tsx. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: In any event, you don't have head tags in your layout file in the repo you've linked. thanks anyway

Comment: Yes it does actually. 

Layout has a custom Meta component:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/c10ac686b57171ce053d344094b7f2d2359abea9/examples/blog-starter/components/layout.tsx#L13

Meta component is using the Head here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/c10ac686b57171ce053d344094b7f2d2359abea9/examples/blog-starter/components/meta.tsx#L6

Then every page in the project (example index.tsx) is wrapped in the Layout component:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/c10ac686b57171ce053d344094b7f2d2359abea9/examples/blog-starter/pages/index.tsx#L20

Comment: I didn't dig into your repo to try and reconcile your code against what you said.  But applying what you've done in your meta component, you've imported Head from next/head rather than next/document. I think this may be part of a solution. Do you know how this concept can be applied in document.tsx, or if the favicons and title can be kept in the app.tsx file? I have tried, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your icon is in a correct format, put in a folder the image  named icon.png and use `imagemagick` to convert it to .icon format

```
brew install imagemagick

convert icon.png -scale 16 tmp/16.png
convert icon.png -scale 32 tmp/32.png
convert icon.png -scale 48 tmp/48.png
convert icon.png -scale 128 tmp/128.png
convert icon.png -scale 256 tmp/256.png

convert tmp/16.png tmp/32.png tmp/48.png tmp/128.png tmp/256.png  icon.ico
```

Then i use to generate a component for the initial head content `HeadContent.js`

```
const HeadContent = () => (
  <>
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      sizes="16x16 24x24 32x32 48x48 64x64"
      href="/favicon.ico"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
    <meta
      name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"
      content="black-translucent"
    />
  </>
);

export default HeadContent;
```

[image: Favicon is in public folder]

Now in `_document.js` you can use the `HeadContent.js`:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import HeadContent from "@components/HeadContent";

export default class extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="es-co">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
          <HeadContent />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i used favicon generator to make the icons. I have each of them saved in my public folder.

Answer (score 0):

inside pages/_app.tsx

```
import Head from "next/head";

<Head>
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version (13.4.4) you can make it work inside the Metadata. Following [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#icons):

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: [{ url: '/icon.png' }, new URL('/icon.png', 'https://example.com')],
    shortcut: ['/shortcut-icon.png'],
    apple: [
      { url: '/apple-icon.png' },
      { url: '/apple-icon-x3.png', sizes: '180x180', type: 'image/png' },
    ],
    other: [
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
        url: '/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

This will create the following:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/shortcut-icon.png" />
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-icon.png" />
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
  href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"
/>
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/icon.png" />
<link
  rel="apple-touch-icon"
  href="/apple-icon-x3.png"
  sizes="180x180"
  type="image/png"
/>
```